# Problem displaying the contents of an array javascript

Tags: javascript

I filled out the matrix according to the data and according to the stipulated condition ... but no result appears to me, which means that the matrix is empty or something similar.

```
function ser(h) {
    var dataX = [];
    var dataY = [];
   for (i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
        if(h.charAt(i) == '0'){
            //---- 1 -----
            dataX.push(i);
            dataY.push(30);
            //---- 2 -----
            dataX.push(i);
            dataY.push(10);
            //---- 3 -----
            dataX.push(i+5);
            dataY.push(10);
            //---- 4 -----
            dataX.push(i+5);
            dataY.push(30);
            //-----
            dataX.push(i+10);
            dataY.push(30);
        }
    }
    console.log(dataY[0]);
}

ser(00); // test
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to pass it as a string:

```
ser("00")
```

---

This expression returns `undefined`:

```
var h = 00
console.log(h.length)
```

and also this will always evaluate to false:

```
h.charAt(i) == '0'
```

since [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) is a string method.